# How do I grab input with Tkinter from an entry field?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to grab input with Tkinter from an entry field and store/use those values. For instance, I have a zip program that takes in the name of the file to be unzipped and the output destination. How would I get those values and pass them through a function, lastly the submit button should be able to unzip upon click. Thanks and if this isn't clear enough I can post the code.

Comment: I've tried the .get() function on the Label where the input should be coming from.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and precisely describe the problem with it (*"I did X, I expected Y to happen, but Z happened instead"*).

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity and lack of information from the question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example file name written in the entry will be automatically passed to the `self.filename` string.

```
self.filename = StringVar()
self.filename_entry = ttk.Entry(mainFrame, width=30, textvariable=self.filename)
self.filename_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
```